# Are "custom URL" handled in User interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 (Experience Manager)?

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, gui-extensions, custom-url

In a Tridion schema, it is possible to add a custom URL in a field definition.

As a result, in the Tridion Content Manager, when editing a component built from this schema, Tridion add a link on the field description.

In Experience Manager, where is the custom URL link?

If Experience manager does not support this feature, what is the best way to configure similar feature? Building an GUI extension ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (out of the box) add a link to the description of a standard field. You could add a GUI Extension, for example...

```
if description contains [[link:
  retrieve linkvalue(descriptionText);
    updateDescriptionWithHyperlink(descriptionText, link)
```

It's likely your code would be version dependant as the DOM may change on the GUI from version to vversion so would have to be checked.

In experience manage there is no such functionality. The user would have to open the component from XM and the custom URL would be available then. The only way to add this would be by GUI Extension but I'm not aware of an extension point that's supported for this...

Answer (score 0):

Custom URLs do work in Experience Manager in Metadata fields. I would therefore move fields to Metadata fields if possible (if not too much content created already).

I am not sure if that applies to the "UI update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1", so give it a quick try on any metadata field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why XPM does not work with custom URLs; when editing content inline you only edit the visible aspects of a component's presentation and custom URLs are intended for scenarios where editors are expected to need "assistance" in filling in the field values (e.g. lat/lng coordinates, lookup from custom database data, etc). If such assistance is needed to allow editors to edit content inline this basically defies the purpose of an inline editor to begin with (to make simple updates simple to do for an editor).

In theory it should be possible to extend XPM however (its GUI is also Anguilla driven so same rules apply as extending the CM webgui but with many more restrictions I would imagine) to add an extra button on the ribbon to open the custom URL for the current context field being inline edited...